# Adding a const to an object literal in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, namespaces

i am new to JS and i am trying to learn more about namespaces.

i am rewriting some animation tasks in ES6 and since use different animations for mobile and desktop animations i decided to put the mobile and desktop animations into their own namespaces.

however i am struggling  to create scrollmagic controller in this namespace so i would be able to use the same controller for all mobile animations.

this is my animation.js

```
export const controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

/**
 * Mobile animations
 */

export const mobile = {

  servicesHome: {
    init: () => {
      const trigger = document.querySelectorAll('.js-service-trigger');
      const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('js-service-tile__fig');

      trigger.forEach((id, i) => {
        const scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
          triggerElement: id,
          reverse: true,
          triggerHook: 1,
          offset: 0,
          duration: 280,
        })
          .on('enter', () => {
            elements[i].classList.add('js-service-tile__fig--is-active');
          })
          .on('leave', () => {
            elements[i].classList.remove('js-service-tile__fig--is-active');
          })
          .addTo(controller);
      });
    },
  },
 };
```

i would prefer to achieve something like :

```
export const mobile = {

  controller: {
    const controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();
  },

  servicesHome: {
    init: () => {
    .
    .
    .
          .addTo(this.controller);
      });
    },
  },
};
```

so the controller could sit inside the namespace its used but i get 'const is a reserved word' error as well as i can't access the controller with this.controller

Comment: Which browser are you testing in? Sounds like one that doesn't support the `const` token/ES6

Comment: @danwellman nah, it's a syntax error. `controller: { const controller` is invalid. It's throwing an error when it sees const being used as a property name.

Comment: i am transpiling it with babel and webpack .... my guess was that i made a big misstake in understanding how to add constructors in a variable in an object literal

Comment: inside `controller:` instead of using `const` use `this.controller = new Scroll...`, and your `this.controller` inside init will work. const is a reserve key for declaring a constant, and you can access it inside its own closure

Comment: @Semi-Friends are you sure? `controller` is an object, not a function. I would expect your solution to throw a `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .` error.

Comment: this.controller will throw the same error ... i basically wanted to have the variable "const controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();" in the object(namespace) mobile

Comment: @evolutionxbox sorry i misread the question, @HenrikEng `controller: new ScrollMagic.Controller()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
const controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();
export const mobile = {
  controller,
  ...
```

Or if `controller` variable isn't used anywhere else, just

```
export const mobile = {
  controller: new ScrollMagic.Controller(),
  ...
```

Comment: Yes i just want to use the specifically for mobile animations to kill it. thanks that works so far ..but now whether i use this.controller or controller it throws 'controller is not defined'
`
export const mobile = {

  controller: new ScrollMagic.Controller(),

  servicesHome: {
    init: () => {
      .
      .
      .
          .addTo(controller);
      });
    },
  },

  changeLogo: {
    init: () => {
      .
      .
      .
        .addTo(this.controller);
      });
    },
  },
};
`

Comment: `this.controller` doesn't exist in your code, as well as `controller`. You need to refer to it as `mobile.controller` in this case.

Comment: awesome :-) it works...didn't know i had to refer to the object inside of a function in the object ..thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome. You could refer to it as `this.controller` if `controller` would be a property of `servicesHome` object *and* `init` would be a normal function and not an arrow (this also depends on how `init` is called). Since controller is defined on another object (`mobile`), it should be referred as `mobile.controller`.